# How to pass a constant defined in \pstVerb as the most right argument of \rput?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\i{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(4,4)
        \pstVerb{/two \i\space 1 add def}
        \rput(2,2){<the value of two>}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How to pass a constant defined in `\pstVerb` as the most right argument of `\rput`?

Comment: what do you want to do with it? you could use `\rput(2,2){\pstVerb{two}}` which will insert `two` into the postscript so put the integer 2 on the stack, or you could use `\pstVerb{two 10 string cvs show}` which will convert the integer 2 into the string (2) (using a buffer of length 10 so assuming the integer not too big) then show it at the current point, but I have no idea where  the current point is in a pstVerb context (not looked at the manual for a decade or two:-) `\pstVerb{two ==} ` make postscript echo 2 (as you will see on the terminal if you run ps2pdf on the dvips output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes some assumptions on dvips, probably but:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\i{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(4,4)
        \pstVerb{/two \i\space 1 add def}
        \rput(2,2){zzz \pstVerb{/Times-Roman findfont 100 scalefont 1 -1 scale setfont two 10 string cvs  show}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let us change `zzz` to `2` and compare both numbers. They look different in size and appearance. Could you make them identical?

Comment: no. even if I restricted completely to assumptions about dvips internal postscript definitions I have no idea what postscript font name dvips would use for the current font. if dvips is doing font subsetting and the 2 isn't used via tex then there may not even be a font defined with that character in. So I ignored the TeX fonts and loaded the core postscript times roman font. Similarly I don't know (but it's possible to discover from the header or asking postscript for the current coordinate matrix what the scale factor should be I just made it 100 -100 so it was visible and not reflected.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for many hours, I found a macro called `\psPrintValue` that is buried in `pst-tools`  package.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-tools}

\def\i{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
        \pstVerb{/two \i\space 1 add def}
        \rput(0.5,0.5){2\psPrintValue{two}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the font is not identical to the font used in TeX. If you have any idea to fix it, please edit this answer.

Edit: Use `times` package to fix the font issue.

Comment: yes looking at the source of that it's doing basically the same as my answer (but more carefully and covering more cases, as it's more than a line of code:-) But it still doesn't try to match fonts. (as you note, if changing the font of the entire document to times is an option that makes it easier to match)